# MongoDB is storing duplicate object keys when using embedded object as a key?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have mongo db collection where I override the _id key with my own object key as opposed to letting mongo use the ObjectId str.

My document object is like this,

```
{'_id': {
     'recipient': 'some-string',
     'my-id': 'some str',
      },
 'data': {...}
 }
```

For some reason I'm able to store duplicate documents when using an embedded document for they _id key.

I'm not getting a duplicate key error and when I upsert my old documents don't update. Not sure what's causing this. According to the mongodoc I can use embedded objects as keys.

**Edit 1**

Here is a sample query from the mongo shell

> >dups = db.update_events.find({"timestamp" : 1384890772.02277}).toArray()

```
[
    {
    "_id" : {
        "campaign-id" : "5982",
        "message-id" : "123@x.mailgun.org",
        "event" : "delivered",
        "recipient" : "a@a.com"
    },
    "timestamp" : 1384890772.02277,
    "campaign-id" : "5982",     
    "event" : "delivered",
    "campaigns" : [ ],
    "delivery-status" : {
        "description" : null,
        "message" : "",
        "code" : 0
    },
    "message" : {
        "headers" : {
        },
        "size" : 2885,

        "attachments" : [ ]
    },
    "dealership" : "RuHOYkYvwh",
    "tags" : [
        "RuHOYkYvwh"
    ],
    "flags" : {
        "is-system-test" : false,
        "is-authenticated" : true,
        "is-test-mode" : false
    }
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "recipient" : "a@a.com",
        "message-id" : "123@x.mailgun.org",
        "event" : "delivered",
        "campaign-id" : "5982",
    },
    "delivery-status" : {
        "description" : null,
        "message" : "",
        "code" : 0
    },
    "message" : {
        "attachments" : [ ],
        "recipients" : [
        ],
        "size" : 2885,
        "headers" : {
        }
    },
    "campaign-id" : "5982",
    "tags" : [
        "RuHOYkYvwh"
    ],
    "campaigns" : [ ],
    "event" : "delivered",
    "timestamp" : 1384890772.02277,
    "flags" : {
        "is-system-test" : false,
        "is-test-mode" : false,
        "is-authenticated" : true
    },
    "dealership" : "RuHOYkYvwh"
}
]

> dups.length
2
```

this is the python code i use to insert it,

```
MyCollection.update(item, item, upsert=True)
```

where 'item' is a python dict w/the '_id'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is order of properties, i.e. your first document is:

```
"_id" : {
    "campaign-id" : "5982",
    "message-id" : "123@x.mailgun.org",
    "event" : "delivered",
    "recipient" : "a@a.com"
},
```

And your second:

```
"_id" : {
    "recipient" : "a@a.com",
    "message-id" : "123@x.mailgun.org",
    "event" : "delivered",
    "campaign-id" : "5982",
},
```

MongoDB actually treats them as two different objects. This is why they are not duplicates. There was a huge argument about this some time ago about how it was stupid that this was the case and there is a JIRA for it somewhere, however, right now my searching abilities are failing me.

### Edit

The underlining problem is that python dicts are not ordered, if you want this to work right you will need to think up of something else.

Comment: Did not know that Mongo treats this differently. This is truly ridiculous. +1 for teaching me something today :-)

Comment: Thanks! The problem was the ordering of my keys.. :/

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake somewhere. This is not possible. _id key would be unique in any situation.

Show your code, which does not rise the Duplicate key error, because here the error is shown:

```
db.a.remove()
db.a.insert({_id : {'recepient' : 1, 'my-id' : 2}, 'data' : 'aaa'})
db.a.insert({_id : {'recepient' : 1, 'my-id' : 2}, 'data' : 'bbb'})
```

> E11000 duplicate key error index: a.a.$*id*  dup key: { : { recepient:
>   1.0, my-id: 2.0 } }

```
db.a.insert({_id : {'recepient' : 1, 'my-id' : 3}, 'data' : 'bbb'})
```

Note that the whole value should be unique, not just your my-id or recepient.

**P.S** you can not update the _id key, so later you will not be able to change neither recipient nor my-id.

Comment: I just put a sample mongo shell query and the pymongo (python) function i use to insert into my collection.. I agree this should be impossible but if i'm reading this right those document keys are exact. I had someone else look at them for me. Also i don't want to update the _id key. I want to update the other data..

Comment: Actually they do look the same. So are the documents. Have no idea how is this possible. Sorry.

Comment: agreed.. it's driving me crazy... gona restart my pc. drop, the collection, if that doesn't do anything re-install mongo, pymongo... :/

Comment: Try to make a reproducible example how you ended up with this duplication keys. If you will be able to do this, you can file a bug report and hope that it will be solved.

Comment: Which version of PyMongo and MongoDB are you using?
Based on your earlier comment, I suspect you are running on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not guarantee the order of the keys in a dictionary,
but MongoDB does care about the order. Different order when inserting or querying means different documents as described by Sammaye.

You can get around that issue by either:

a) use Python's collection.OrderedDict (new in 2.7)

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

b) use PyMongo's bson.son

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Create your '_id' key with either of the above objects and the keys in the inserted document will be the same as the order you use in your Python code.